Quick Action in visual studio appears in small font size
I am currently using visual studio 2022 community version. And i having this issues where the code review feature "Quick Action" appears in small font size. And i tried to increase it size, but i cannot find the options to increase it .So help me with this issue.
I checked in tools->options for any options to increase its size but i cant find out anything to solve my issue.

Can you share a screenshot about your problem with Quick Actions window that you encountered?

The answer is so dumb.  I had this issue and finally decided to solve it...
Got to your font settings and make your font size for text editor small like 10 or so.
Now hold ctr and scroll your text up and viola.. problem solved

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
